# BrowserSync not loading vhost via proxy

Tags: browser-sync

Browser Sync is not proxying `http://localhost:80`. It just hangs and eventually times out. I can access `http://localhost:80` directly in the browser with no problems.

> browser-sync start --proxy 'http://localhost:80' --logLevel 'debug'

```
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Finding an empty port
[BS] [debug] Found a free port: 3000
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: port - 3000
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Finding an empty port
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Getting an extra port for Proxy
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Getting an extra port for Proxy
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Checking online status
[BS] [debug] Resolved www.google.com, setting online: true
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: online - true
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Checking online status
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Resolve user plugins from options
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Resolve user plugins from options
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Set Urls and other options that rely on port/online status
[BS] [debug] Setting multiple Options
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Set Urls and other options that rely on port/online status
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Setting Internal Events
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Setting Internal Events
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Setting file watchers
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Setting file watchers
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Merging middlewares from core + plugins
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: middleware - List []
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Merging middlewares from core + plugins
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the Server
[BS] [debug] Proxy running, proxing: http://localhost:80
[BS] [debug] Running mode: PROXY
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the Server
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the HTTPS Tunnel
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the HTTPS Tunnel
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the web-socket server
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: clientEvents - List [ "scroll", "scroll:element", "input:text", "input:toggles", "form:submit", "form:reset", "click" ]
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the web-socket server
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Starting the UI
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: session - 1479585487733
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Setting default plugins
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Setting default plugins
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Finding a free port
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Finding a free port
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Setting options also relevant to UI from BS
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Setting options also relevant to UI from BS
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Setting available URLS for UI
[BS] [debug] Getting option via path: urls
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Setting available URLS for UI
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Starting the Control Panel Server
[BS] [UI] Using port 3001
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Starting the Control Panel Server
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Add element events
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Add element events
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Registering default plugins
[BS] [debug] Getting option via path: urls,external
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Registering default plugins
[BS] [UI] Starting Step: Add options setting event
[BS] [UI] Step Complete: Add options setting event
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Starting the UI
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Merge UI settings
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: urls - Map { "local": "http://localhost:3000", "external": "http://192.168.0.9:3000", "ui": "http://localhost:3001", "ui-external": "http://192.168.0.9:3001" }
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Merge UI settings
[BS] [debug] -> Starting Step: Init user plugins
[BS] [debug] Setting Option: userPlugins -
[BS] [debug] +  Step Complete: Init user plugins
[BS] Proxying: http://localhost:80
[BS] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.0.9:3000
 ------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.0.9:3001
 ------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using IPv6 (::1:80) in my hosts file. I switched to IPv4 (127.0.0.1:80) and it's working as expected now.